# maven-ant .war file without web.xml file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, ant

I have a important question ,
I don't have a `web.xml` in my java project and i want to create a `.war` file of that project.
**Can i do that?** as I have searched all over but did not found anything, can you please help me out here?

I have `pom.xml` in the project and it has all the dependencies.

I have created a maven project and then i am using the **maven-ant** plugin, so, in ant, i want to create `.war file`.

After building it through `ant`, I have `build.xml and maven-build.xml` files.
Please help me out here!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder *project/target* to certify your .war was not created

Your pom.xml need have this structure after your dependencies to generate .war

```
<build>
 <finalName>your .war name</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "war" task of ant with parameter `needxmlfile` set to false